# mostrar resultado de array javascript dentro de un select

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bucle-for, select

Tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy intentando mostrar dentro de un `select`, el resultado de un `for` que ejecuto en *JS*. El resultado lo mando mediante `ajax` a un `div` pero no se que estoy haciendo mal que si coloco el `div` fuera del `select` si me da los resultados pero si lo coloco dentro del `select` me arroja como que no tengo ningún `div` con ese ID en la pagina.

Por acá les dejo el código.

Código del `select`

```
//Departamento

<select class="form-select form-select-sm click_depart" name="Nestado"  id="Nestado"> 
   <div id="contenido_depart_consult_market"></div>
</select>
```

Código del *JS*

```
for (let i = 0; i < result_consult.length; i++) {
  html = "<option value=" + result_consult[i].idpais + "> " + result_consult[i].pais + "</option>";
  document.getElementById('contenido_depart_consult_market').innerHTML += html;
}
```

El *JS* me da el resultado sin problema cuando coloco el `div` fuera del `select`. También intenté crear el botón completo desde *JS*, pero soy nuevo en esto no lo logré. Uno de los intentos fallidos fue este, aquí les dejo el código:

### Actualización

Logré crear el botón completo, por aca les dejo el código, aunque no se si es lo mas practico, ya que pensaba que el botón quedara visible  y a medida que el otro `select` cambiara los datos pues a este le cambiaran los suyos de manera interna y no que apareciera un `select` nuevamente cargando.

```
let btn_html = "<select class='form-select form-select-sm click_depart' name='Nestado'  id='Nestado'><option value=0>Todos</option>";

let final_btn_html = "</select>";
//Declaración normal
var html = new Array();
//Declaración resumida

for (let i = 0; i < result_consult.length; i++) {
  if (result_consult[i].pais == "Venezuela") {
    html[i] = "<option value=" + result_consult[i].idpa + "> " + result_consult[i].pais + "</option>";
  }
}
document.getElementById('contenido_depart_consult_market').innerHTML += btn_html += html += final_btn_html;
```

Comment: Mira de cambiar esto: `btn_html += html += final_btn_html;` por esto: `btn_html + html + final_btn_html;`, a ver si hay suerte

Comment: hola amigo, allí edite el código, logre crear el botón completo, aunque no me parece lo mas practico ya que quería que al cambiar el otro select por ejemplo pais, me aparecieran los departamentos dentro de este select en la parte interna, pero bueno así carga el select completo que me parece que no esta tan mal para esta nuevo en esto igual si tiene alguna forma mejor le agradezco su colaboración

Comment: Dentro de un `select`, no pongas un `div`. Dentro de un select solo pueden ir sus elementos permitidos, que creo que son `option` y `optgroup` solo.  Lo que debes hacer es borrar el div y poner el `id="contenido_depart_consult_market"` en el `<select>` y hacer el cambio que te he dicho en mi anterior comentario, y debería funcionarte mejor

Comment: ah, y cambia esto también:  `html[i] = `   por esto `html += `, pero antes, una linea por encima del inicio del bucle: `for (let i = 0; i < result_consult.length; i++){`  inicias la variable agregando esta línea:  `let html = ''` para indicarle que será una variable de texto, y tambien borra esta línea: `var html = new Array();`

Comment: listo ya te indico estoy agregando esos cambios, gracias.

Comment: En cuanto a los `select` dependientes (eso que dices que eliges una cosa y el otro select cambia)  es un poco más complejo de explicar, y se puede hacer de varias formas, pero no sabemos como es el origen de ambos datos de los select, si los tienes ya cargados durante la carga inicial de la página o los estas consiguiendo por ajax, pues no lo pones en la pregunta.  Normalmente se hace usando la función `addEventListener` que te permite poner a la escucha el evento **change** del primer select, y si detecta cambios entonces puedes filtrar el contenido del segundo `select` dentro de esa función

Comment: Listo amigo ya quedo, ya vi que colocando el id en option le puedo pasar los valores tambien de una vez sin crear el boton, muchas gracias me a ayudado mucho su informacion y si yo tengo todo cargado desde el inicio e iba cargando todo por ajax, pero los bucles de foreach los estaba haciendo con php y ps ahora estoy cambiando todo a JS y de eso si me cuesta un poco pero bueno todo sea por darle mas velocidad a la pagina